# More Primary / Auto-adding unique IDs per one table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Is it possible to have two and more primary/automatic-adding unique IDs per one table in MySQL? For example:

Primary Key (INT,11);shop_id;invoice_id

```
1;200;2001
1;201;2011
2;200;2002
2;201;2012
```

Is it possible to set this to MySQL table ? -> So there are more primary keys for some other value in the table.. ?

I am looking for more auto-increments in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for [AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html)? you can do this for MyISAM tables.

Comment: I know I could take a peek to documentation but what is MyISAM table? can i convert my table to it?

Comment: MyISAM [1] is MySQL's default storage engine (non-transaction-safe). If your table isn't MyISAM yet (SHOW CREATE TABLE t, look for "ENGINE=..." ), you can convert to it with

  ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = MYISAM;

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single AUTO_INCREMENT column per table in MySQL.  You can only have a single PRIMARY key in a table in MySQL, but it can be a composite key and consist of more than one column.

But from the example you gave, it looks like you're asking for something different.  Can you clarify?